# django establish correct relationships between models

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, trying to figure out how to set up my models so that I can accomplish my idea. On my web app, many passengers can book many flights via a form.

I want to display all passengers that are associated with a particular flight.

Example: *London => Paris | [ "Bob", "Alice", "Bill" ]* and I will then iterate though that list in my template.

Sorry if this is too easy for you.

I tried to get the individual flight by id in views.py and then displaying the data in the template: {{ london.passengers.name }} but it returns None

**views.py**

```
def flights(request):

    london = Flight.objects.get(id=1)
    context = {'london': london}
    return render(request, 'flights.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
# Passenger model.
class Passenger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# Flight model.
class Flight(models.Model):
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duration = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(Passenger)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.origin + " => " + self.destination
```

Answer (score 3):

The list of `Passenger` objets associated with `flight` can be obtained with:

```
def flights(request):
    london = Flight.objects.get(id=1)
    passengers = london.passengers.all()
    context = { 'london': london, 'passengers': passengers }
    return render(request, 'flights.html', context)
```

and then render this in the template with:

```
{% for passenger in passengers %}
    {{ passenger.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can just access it in the template with `london.passengers.all`, and iterate over it with:

```
{% for passenger in london.passengers.all %}
    {{ passenger.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I personally prefer determining the `passengers` in the view, since a view determine *what* will be rendered, and a template only determines *how* that will be rendered.